# Simple For loops not working on cs6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

In my code I have a few for loops in the main timeline that look like this

```
for (i = 0; i<2*speedY; i++)
    {
code
}
```

I've done this exact syntax many times and there have been no issues, however when I did it it gave me the error that i is undefined. I then tried the same loops defining i as var i:int; however now it just gave me a namespace error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the variable `i` within the loop itself and don't need the variable beyond the scope of the loop, you can also declare it within the loop parameters:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            trace(i);
}
```

In terms of performance it's a marginal difference, however it's generally a good practice to declare variables only within the scope in which they will be used.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the `undefined` error, you have to define your variable `i`, but also to avoid the `namespace` error you should do that once. So you can do that like this :

```
var i:int;

// 1st for loop
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    trace('1 : '+i);
}

// 2nd for loop
for(i = 5; i > 0; i--){
    trace('2 : ' + i);
}
```

Comment: Well that's the right answer although I tested it again and it works(without defining i) which is odd but thanks anyway. –  Altrows 2 hours ago